# Translating SQL request to django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, subquery

I am trying to create a request(in django) that will return an array of posts(only user's posts, which the current user in following).
Here are my models

Posts:

```
class Post(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField("Headline", max_length=100)
      body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
      thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Following/followers:

```
class FollowUser(models.Model):
      who_id = models.IntegerField()
      whom_id = models.IntegerField()
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Users:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
      profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_u_name, default='default.png', blank=True)
      bio = models.TextField(null=True)
      website = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
      location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

      def __unicode__(self):
           return "%s's profile" % self.user
```

SQL request that I've created:

```
     SELECT *  FROM POSTS Where user_id IN (select whom_id from FOLLOWERS Where user_id = 1 )
```

So, I've tried to translate this sql code to django-like but I wasn't able.
The main problem is that i can't request for an array.

Need help!
Thanks

Comment: I think your who_id and whom_id should also be foreign key to User model. That is the right way and will make your query easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Post.objects.filter(user_id__in=FollowUser.objects.filter(who_id=1).values_list('whom_id'))
```

You can use this in your `views.py` by using the `request` parameter

```
Post.objects.filter(user_id__in=FollowUser.objects.filter(who_id=request.user.id).values_list('whom_id'))
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much! I was looking for "user_id__in" and "values_list" but i didnt know how to implement them. And this is exactly it. Everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Table names are automatically generated by combining the name of the app and the lowercase name of the model. Try to use `<appname>_posts`

Comment: yes, i know. But actually i want a request looking like:              f = FollowUser.objects.all().filter(who_id=request.user.id)                p = Posts.objects.all().filter(user_id=f.whom_id)
    but this doesn't work cuz it returns a single objects, also seems i have a mistake here